# Appending an empty row in csv file using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to generate a `CSV` output with Headers in the first row then left empty in the second row and the data starts from the third row. How to generate this using **DataWeave 2.0**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) what you want to generate is NOT a CSV file.

The closest you can get to it is to add a row with no data, which can be accomplished with the DW expression below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
var data = [
    {
        header1: "v1",
        header2: "v2",
        header3: "v3"
    },
    {
        header1: "v4",
        header2: "v5",
        header3: "v6"
    }
]

var empty = {
    header1: "",
    header2: "",
    header3: ""
}

---
empty >> data
```

Comment: Thanks @George. But how to remove commas in empty row

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is what George posted. The output with an empty row is not a valid CSV and for that reason a CSV output in DataWeave can not be used to generate it. You can however hack it your way by writing the header and the data as separate strings and concatenating a newline in the middle. I don't recommend to do this but if you have some weird requirement and you are forced to do it, I modified George's example to do it.

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var data = [
    {
        header1: "v1",
        header2: "v2",
        header3: "v3"
    },
    {
        header1: "v4",
        header2: "v5",
        header3: "v6"
    }
]

var headers = data[0] mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (index): key) // take the headers from the first row of data to be used as the data of the first row in the output
---
write(headers, "application/csv", {header:false}) ++ "\n" ++ write(data, "application/csv", {header:false})
```